# How do I append the results of a local job script in R into an Excel file?

Tags: r, excel

I'm running dozens of scripts in R/RStudio as local jobs and I have an Excel File where I'm consolidating the results. Each run produces two values that I copy/paste into Excel. Is there a way to automate the saving of the results directly into the respective column of the Excel file?

For example, my spreadsheet is called FFNN with columns `variance` and `deviance` and each time my script runs I would like the respective results to be saved into a cell in those columns.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, unsure why the RStudio tag was removed as this (partly) has to do with the local job functionality of RStudio.

Comment: Consider exporting results to a two-column CSV then copy/paste once to final spreadsheet.  Or look into R-Excel packages to write results to worksheet.

Comment: `openxlsx` has excellent features to create, read, write to and append to excel files. You can also programmatically format your excel output.